# Можно ли оформлять диалог сначала в подбор с помощью кавычек, а потом с помошью тире с нового абзаца?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, диалог, редактура, корректура

Ситуация такая: текст не вмещается на одной странице из-за диалогов, оформленных с помощью тире и нового абзаца. Без изменения содержания текста, т.е. без редактуры, можно ли ***часть*** диалога оформить с помощью кавычек в подбор. Не будет ли здесь нарушение каких-то правил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от самого текста. В каких-то условиях можно. Вот посмотрите у Розенталя:

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=161